# Replicating each row of the dataframe for 30 days (i.e. a month) using for loop

Tags: python

I have a data frame with 4095 entries. I need to create a reference data frame with these entries replicating each row 30 times i.e. a month and also add a new column with Date.

Existing data frame:
S.N Type   Location
1   Cash   LA
2   D.Card NY

Desired Output
S.N  Type  Location Date

1. Cash  LA       01/01/2020
2. Cash  LA       01/02/2020
   .
   .
   .
3. Cash  LA       01/30/2020

Please can anyone suggest how can I do it, using for loop or any loop, in python?

Comment: Can you show your work so wr can see what has been done so far. Also not every month has 30 days. Some have 31 and Feb has 28/29. Do you want to replicate based on calendar days. Can you be more specific in your ask. And can you please share sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using a loop and is pretty straightforward.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame([
    # sample data
    {"S.N. Type":"Cash", "Location":"LA"},
    {"S.N. Type":"Loan", "Location":"TX"},
    {"S.N. Type":"Cash", "Location":"NY"}])
print(df)

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for row in range(len(df)):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date:': pd.date_range(dt.date(2020,1,1), dt.date(2020,1,31)+pd.DateOffset(-1))})
    df2["S.N. Type"] = df.iloc[row, 0]
    df2["Location"] = df.iloc[row, 1]
    df3 = df3.append(df2)
df3 = df3.reset_index()    
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
  S.N. Type Location
0      Cash       LA
1      Loan       TX
2      Cash       NY
    index      Date: S.N. Type Location
0       0 2020-01-01      Cash       LA
1       1 2020-01-02      Cash       LA
2       2 2020-01-03      Cash       LA
3       3 2020-01-04      Cash       LA
4       4 2020-01-05      Cash       LA
..    ...        ...       ...      ...
85     25 2020-01-26      Cash       NY
86     26 2020-01-27      Cash       NY
87     27 2020-01-28      Cash       NY
88     28 2020-01-29      Cash       NY
89     29 2020-01-30      Cash       NY
```

Comment: I get this error (TypeError: an integer is required (got type str))

Comment: I used :'Date':(pd.date_range(start='2020-04-01', end='2020-04-30', freq='1D')) instead and it worked. Anyways thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

A straight Cartesian product between you data and a data frame of wanted days does it.

```
(pd.DataFrame([
    # sample data
    {"S.N. Type":"Cash", "Location":"LA"},
    {"S.N. Type":"Loan", "Location":"LA"},
    {"S.N. Type":"Cash", "Location":"NY"},
])
 # cartesian product to all days between two days
 # couldn't remeber number of days in August so used an offset...
 .assign(foo=1)
 .merge(pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(dt.date(2020,6,1), dt.date(2020,9,1)+pd.DateOffset(-1))})
        .assign(foo=1),on="foo")
 .drop(columns="foo")
)
```

### output

```
    S.N. Type   Location    Date
0   Cash    LA  2020-06-01
1   Cash    LA  2020-06-02
2   Cash    LA  2020-06-03
3   Cash    LA  2020-06-04
4   Cash    LA  2020-06-05
... ... ... ...
271 Cash    NY  2020-08-27
272 Cash    NY  2020-08-28
273 Cash    NY  2020-08-29
274 Cash    NY  2020-08-30
275 Cash    NY  2020-08-31
276 rows × 3 columns
```

Comment: It works as well, just had to make some changes in the Date format. Anyways thank you so much.